# diffrent response IE-8 and FF getElementById()

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, behavior, getelementbyid

i have a function what does the following

```
function test() {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML="show wait";

    // do stuff

    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML="show finished";
}
```

In FF the div will show "show wait", do the other stuff for 4 seconds and
then show "show finished"

In IE it will only show "show finished". If i put an alert() after or before the "do stuff" it will show "show wait".

What can I do to solve it, i know i can split the function, any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read Richard's explanation for why it doesn't work. As for a solution,
a quick hack:

```
function test() {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML="show wait";

    setTimeout(function(){
        // do stuff

        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML="show finished";
    },1)
}
```

The reason this works is that `setTimeout` schedules the "do stuff" code to be executed later thereby allowing the browser to exit script execution mode and enter DOM rendering mode so that the `"show wait"` text can be drawn onto the screen.

Answer (score 1):

IE is not showing any updates until you return the thread of control to the browser. A call to alert will do this (your script waits for a user action).

Either don't rely on visible UI changes while you have the thread of execution, or do something like using a timer to continue the second part of your script after (briefly) returning the thread of execution.